# regex match mongoid condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have item[:name] and I would like to be able to use

```
(item[:name].scan(/[a-z0-9\s]/i).join rescue "") =~ Regexp.new(business.scan(/[a-z0-9\s]/i).join, true)
```

as a condition in mongoid.  Is there a way to do this?  The only solution I have come up with is getting all items, then iterating over that array, doing the regex at that point in time.

The goal of this is to find "John's" when the website is searched for "Johns" and vice versa.

Thanks

Comment: ever come up with a good solution to this?

Comment: I have posted my code, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i ended up using.

```
def self.find_by_name_or_organization(business = nil)
  businesses = self.all(:order => "name ASC")
  businesses.delete(nil)

  if business && !(business.nil? || business.to_s == '')
    final_business_array = Array.new

    businesses.each do |item|
      if (item[:organization].scan(/[a-z0-9\s]/i).join rescue "") =~ Regexp.new(business.scan(/[a-z0-9\s]/i).join, true) ||
        (item[:name].scan(/[a-z0-9\s]/i).join rescue "") =~ Regexp.new(business.scan(/[a-z0-9\s]/i).join, true)
          final_business_array.push(item)
      end
    end

    final_business_array
  else
    businesses
  end
end
```